# Intel threaded building blocks gcc version

Tags: gcc, parallel-processing, intel, tbb, gcc4.8

I have installed intel parallel studio. However looking at the gcc compiler in the directory structure of tbb it appears 4.8 is used. I am trying to build another repository that relies on tbb which is giving the following error which Im fairly certain is caused by the old version of gcc.

error:

```
/usr/include/tbb/concurrent_vector.h(667): error: ambiguous "?" operation: second operand of type "tbb::internal::concurrent_vector_base_v3::size_type" can be converted to third operand type "tbb::atomic<unsigned long>", and vice versa

/usr/include/tbb/concurrent_vector.h(680): error: ambiguous "?" operation: second operand of type "tbb::internal::concurrent_vector_base_v3::size_type" can be converted to third operand type "tbb::atomic<unsigned long>", and vice versa

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00000d0e_00000000-4_gpu_handle.cpp4.ii".
make: *** [build/objs/cuda/tensor/gpu_handle.o] Error 2
```

the directory structure of tbb is as follows

```
mm470@pc5-036-l:~/usr/parallel_studio_xe_2020/compilers_and_libraries_2020/linux/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8 $ dir
libtbb.so  libtbb.so.2  libtbb_debug.so.2  libtbbmalloc.so  libtbbmalloc.so.2  libtbbmalloc_debug.so.2
```

Does anyone know firstly if my hunch about the gcc version causing this error is correct and secondly how I would go about getting parallel studio installed with a newer version of gcc. My gcc on the computer is a higher version.

```
mm470@pc5-036-l:~/usr/parallel_studio_xe_2020/compilers_and_libraries_2020/linux/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8 $ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.3.1 20170216 (Red Hat 6.3.1-3)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Did you ever actually figure this out? I have hit the same.

Answer (score 1):

gcc version is related to gnu runtime which will be used. AFAIR Intel compiler doesn't provide own runtime and using the gnu runtime. They(gcc runtime) had some breaking changes between earlier and 4.8 version.

AFAIS `/usr/include/tbb/concurrent_vector.h` is your local installed TBB from your linux distributive, not from compiler bundle. Try to source compiler environment script to setup different PATHes.